# What I'm doing wrong on MySql?

Tags: mysql

I wanna delete with PHP a user but mysql say that the username does not exist

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE username =".$auser['username']." LIMIT 1
```

In my mysql I have 2 columns

```
ID | USERNAMES
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it clearly says `username does not exist`,

Change `username` to `usernames` in `WHERE` clause.

Also add single quotes `'` to variable in `WHERE` clause.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE usernames = '".$auser['username']."' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Can you say why It's so important to use `'` (ps: working thanxs)

Comment: You need to enclose `strings` in single quotes.

Comment: okay understand thanx you